# Flutter `launchUrl` redirect to PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, view

I am using `flutter` `launchUrl` on android, I tested it downloading `pdf`s as well, works fine. But if I have a `.php` url which downloads a PDF I get a white screen. I could set `mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication` in order to switch to the downloads. Is there a way to open the file in the browser or using the default app?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
  await launchUrl(uri,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
}
```

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example in order for us to test what you are experiencing? Maybe the pdf is the problem too, so we need a URL

Comment: Dear bro/sis, .PHP is a Server interpreted file. Without PHP support and A Server beside of it you cannot open any .PHP interpreted as HTML. Forget it and change approach of your app ideas ;) . Scordatelo (alemno che tu non chiami un url esterno del server che ospita i tuoi PHP)....

Comment: Well, let's take this as example: https://www.hgv.it/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=5179&token=64562a31c2cad94fa426c8245bec7ceee3f3cf75